# Planes in 3D that form infinite soln

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this mathematical construction i wish to create.
I have a point, say (1,-3,5), and to make things simple decided on a direction vector m = (0,0,1), i now put this together as a vector equation of a line:

> > line == (x,y,z) = (1,-3,5) + t(0,0,1), where t belongs to real numbers.

I want to construct 3 planes that intersect to give this line.
Also want the planes to form in such a way that the angle between them is the same. That is symmetrically distributed, see image attached.
[image]

My approach was to construct a normal to the direction vector, and then have that normal as the first normal for the first plane that contains this line. But constructing the 2nd and 3rd planes with ensuring the angles between them to be the same is difficult, seems like trial and error using dot product or cross product to create these, the numbers to restrict to this condition to create vectors becomes very difficult.

Hope someone has some insight on this, or another approach to this.

Comment: Your approach will work. To get the angles right, repeatedly rotate your first vector by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$ where $n$ is the number of planes you want to construct.

Comment: Thanks, how can i rotate a vector, without using rotation matrices.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the formula seems something that is good. When they say : "If v is a vector in ℝ3 and k is a unit vector describing an axis of rotation about which v rotates by an angle θ :, the Unit Vector-k, what would that be in terms of my structures, would that be my direction vector of the line? Hope you can let me  know "-amd"